# Branch.io: detect first install from Unity

Tags: installation, unity-game-engine, branch.io

Trying to detect the first install event from branch.io link (succesfully implement link creating and sharing). I am using Unity branch sdk. The feature i try to create:

1. user_1 creates and share link to user_2.
2. When user_2 opens the link and install app i need to reward both of them (with inner in-game coins)

So i succesfully implement the 1. but I cant understand how to detect is user_2 installs the app or simply open it. All data that comes from branch.io UniversalObject callback doesn't contain information that i need.

Which the correct way to detect the install from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex from Branch here.

The callback parameter you need is `+is_first_session`. This is one of the parameters returned when the Branch session is initiated each time your app opens [(you can find all all these parameters here)](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#branch-provided-data-parameters-in-callback). If this returns true, then that device has just installed the app (instead of opening it).

However, note that when these parameters are returned, it's impossible to immediately determine if the *user* is new (what you want), the *device* is new (not what you want, since the reward could be given twice if the user has installed on multiple devices), or neither (the user deleted the app and reinstalled on the same device). You would probably want to hold off on actually awarding the referral points until after the user has logged in with some sort of unique ID.

Branch also has a built-in feature for [tracking referral points](https://dev.branch.io/features/referral-programs/overview) that might be useful. That lets you configure all the rules using the dashboard UI instead of needing to do it programmatically inside your app.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I am trying to use "is_first_session" because i need to award both player - the one who send invite and the one who install game by invite in moment when the app was opened after fresh install by second player. As far as i know referral points could only reward the player who was invited

Comment: @Rusty good point. You would want to record the ID of the user who sent the invite as custom data in the link. The invit*ing* user's ID would be returned when you initialize the Branch session for the invit*ed* user, and then you can award referral points to both users